# Has Tor Browser stopped displaying circuits?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, onion-routing, circuit

I started using Tor v4 most intrigued by the display of the circuit path it followed, 4 nodes from at least 2 countries and usually 3 or 4.

Now at v9 I don't see it anymore. Has display of the information been purposely omitted?

Comment: See here: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/managing-identities/#the-url-bar

Answer (score 1):

Click on the letter "i" icon on your address bar:

[image]